# ListView onItemClickListener never triggered

Tags: android, listview, focus

I created a custom view which overrides onTouchListener in order to have differents images drown depending on the action performed by the user. (To change the background of the view when the user click on it for example).

I want to use this custom view in a ListView, so I created a custom adapter which displays all my views but the onItemClickListener of my ListView is never triggered.

What can I do ?

Here's the code from my Custom View:

```
    @Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    switch (event.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        setMode(MODE_SELECTED);
        invalidate();
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        setMode(MODE_NONE);
        invalidate();
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
        setMode(MODE_NONE);
        invalidate();
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE:
        setMode(MODE_NONE);
        invalidate();
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: You are probably returning true from your onTouch listener which indicates to the system that you've handled the event, thus it won't get passed further up the chain i.e. to the onItemClick of the ListView. Post the code that you are using and your desired outcome and we can help you more.

Comment: Well, first thing you can do is to post your code so that others can figure out where you are going wrong.

Comment: Try to set your custom view focusable property to false

Comment: I already tried, I've got exactly the same problem (either my onTouch return true or false)

Comment: Is there no other way for me to change images when the user clicks on the view instead of overriding onTouch ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found a solution : I use StateListDrawable and it avoids me to override the onTouch of my custom view !